# getCurrentCell() isn't returning anything

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function ccell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell()
}
```

I put this function on a cell and all I get is an empty cell regardless of what cell is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't running because there is nothing that is calling it. Is this inside of a Button.Click event? So that when you click on a new cell, it fires off this line every time?

Comment: Do cells not update unless some event forces them to?

This is just inside a cell.

Comment: Yes I believe so. If this code isn't in a Mouse.Click Event (or some other section of code that will kick off when a cell is changed), it won't be running that code every time you click on a cell.